# Rollup Helper - Only do rollup for specific record type?

Tags: rolluphelper

#### Question

Is it possible to use rollup helper to define a rollup that is only calculated for particular record type?

#### Background

We're rebuilding a UI for generating a custom object which has multiple children. The current UI is built with visualforce and manually calculates some "rollup" values. We're now using skuid to generate the objects and would like to use rollup helper to do the calculation. There will be initial pilot period and I'd like to have the rollup helper do the calculation for the "rollup" values for the v2 record type, but let the old visualforce controller continue doing the calculations for the v1 record type. I know I can filter the records included in the rollup, but is there anyway to filter which parents rollup helper manages the rollup helper for?

I've reviewed the documentation and it doesn't appear to be there, but was hoping to check with the community before resorting to a trigger or other alternatives ...

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack, but ended up creating a new target for the rollup, then used workflow to copy it over to the desired target for just the record type I cared about. Yay field bloat!

Comment: you should mark this answer as the resolution to get it off the Community never-ending resurfacing train

Comment: @crop1645, once it's accepted no one ever answers, and mine is a hack, left it open in case some one else has a more direct solution (also i have to wait several days before i can do that and never remember), if it looks like the correct answer to you do upvote it

Comment: @crop1645 also, what's the Community never-ending resurfacing train?

Comment: sorry - I meant that unsolved questions keep popping up in the stream waiting for someone to respond (which almost never happens). I think your solution is in fact the only solution for these limitations on criteria used for RSF and pseudoRSF solutions

Comment: @crop1645 oh i see, that's actually the idea though, i want this to crop up in 6 months when there actually is a solution without a workaround, also, i think with the upvote it won't show up an unanswered questions anymore, since it has one upvoted answer